# Deleting files and prompting user for his decision

Tags: bash, rm

```
printf "$(find "./RIT/"${neki_array["letnik"]}"" -name "*" )\n">> tmpfile
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]] ; do
      echo "Do you want to delete "$line"? y|Y or n|N" 
      read anwser
      if [ $anwser="y" ] || [ $anwser="Y" ] ; then
         rm -rf "$line"
      fi
done <tmpfile
rm -f tmpfile
```

That is my code. What I am trying to do is save every sub folder or text file to my temporary file called tmpfile. When I'm done with that i read this file line by line and ask user if he wants to delete it. The problem is that it skips user input and the if statement and deletes all of the folders.

Comment: If you read the docs, you'll see that `-f` is described as (among other things) "never prompt". What do you *expect* to happen when you pass a "never prompt" option alongside one which asks for prompting?

Comment: ...anyhow, `rm` is not part of bash, and bash has no control over its behavior (you can have completely different versions of rm installed alongside the same version of bash). If you *really* want `rm` itself to give different behavior, this is a question for your OS vendor, not a question about bash. By contrast, if you want to write a bash script that does its own prompting before calling `rm`, that's a reasonable thing to try to do, and if you show your efforts and a specific, narrow bug you hit in the process, we may be in a place to assist.

Comment: ...insofar as you're asking a question about how UNIX tools behave rather than a question about scripting, though, you're better off at [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) rather than here.

Comment: I am trying to read user input for y or n and it dosen't seem to work:                
   echo -n "Do you want to delete "$line"? y|Y or n|N" 
   read -n 1 anwser

Comment: That's a nice concrete problem, and thus a likely better fit for our format -- [edit] it into the question (since there aren't any answers -- we frown on editing *answered* questions in ways that invalidate existing answers) as a [mcve] with a better description (what does "doesn't seem to work" mean?), and we should be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 printf "$(find "./RIT/"${neki_array["letnik"]}"" -name "*" )\n">> tmpfile
        while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]] ; do
            echo "Do you want to delete "$line"? y|Y or n|N" 
            read anwser < /dev/tty
            case $anwser in
                y|Y)
                    rm -rf "$line";;
                *)
                    echo "You choose not to delete"
            esac
        done <tmpfile
        rm -f tmpfile
```

I used the < /dev/tty and put a switch case insted of if and it worked.